# Not able to get ajax Status Code 404

Tags: jquery, ajax, error-handling, http-status-code-404

I am trying to add some code into the statusCode function of my ajax call though just not able to!

I have managed a workaround through the error() function however I want to specifically handle only for 404 cases. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Please help:
https://jsfiddle.net/9pyk5vmh/

```
var arr = ['http://pbs.twimg.com/media/CEPW00rVA5.jpg',
    'http://pbs.twimg.com/media/CEO6b85UsAEBhzI.jpg',
    'http://pbs.twimg.com/media/CEAQweFUUAAP8yP.jpg',
    'http://pbs.twimg.com/media/CD_5TzEUgAEVkus.jpg',
    'http://pbs.twimg.com/media/CD_oB24UsAAO-li.jpg',
    'http://pbs.twimg.com/media/CD_iyBDUkAAUyW-.jpg',
    'http://pbs.twimg.com/media/CD_iZvKUUAAPygN.jpg',
    'http://pbs.twimg.com/media/CD_fzKSUkAEaUdD.jpg'
];

for (var i in arr) {
    var url = arr[i];
    //console.log(i);
    $.ajax({
        type: "HEAD",
        url: url,
        async: true,
        statusCode: {
            404: function () {
                alert('404!');
            }
        },
        error: function (message, text, response) {
            arr.splice(i, 1);
        }
    });
}

for (i in arr) {
    var img = $('<img>'); //Equivalent: $(document.createElement('img'))
    img.attr('src', arr[i]);
    img.appendTo('#imagediv');
}
```